# How to plot all the columns of a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, r-faq

The data frame has n columns and I would like to get n plots, one plot for each column.

I'm a newbie and I am not fluent in R, anyway I found two solutions.

The first one works but it does not print the column name (and I need them!):

```
data <- read.csv("sample.csv",header=T,sep=",")
for ( c in data ) plot( c, type="l" )
```

The second one works better because it prints the column name:

```
data <- read.csv("sample.csv",header=T,sep=",")
for ( i in seq(1,length( data ),1) ) plot(data[,i],ylab=names(data[i]),type="l")
```

Is there any better (from the R language point of view) solutions?

Comment: In your second second example, I'd initialize the loop like this `for(i in seq_along(dat))` and I wouldn't call my data `data` either.

Comment: Your `read.csv` can be reduced to `read.csv("sample.csv")` since the other arguments are just being set to their default values.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The `ggplot2` package takes a little bit of learning, but the results look really nice, you get nice legends, plus many other nice features, all without having to write much code.

```
require(ggplot2)
require(reshape2)
df <- data.frame(time = 1:10,
                 a = cumsum(rnorm(10)),
                 b = cumsum(rnorm(10)),
                 c = cumsum(rnorm(10)))
df <- melt(df ,  id.vars = 'time', variable.name = 'series')

# plot on same grid, each series colored differently -- 
# good if the series have same scale
ggplot(df, aes(time,value)) + geom_line(aes(colour = series))

# or plot on different plots
ggplot(df, aes(time,value)) + geom_line() + facet_grid(series ~ .)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Nice answer but why do you actually require reshape ?

Comment: Thanks @VerenaHaunschmid I have figured that out afterwards :-)

Comment: It is required by melt

Answer (score 48):

There is very simple way to plot all columns from a data frame using separate panels or the same panel:

```
plot.ts(data)
```

Which yields (where X1 - X4 are column names):

[image]

Have look at ?plot.ts for all the options.

If you wan't more control over your plotting function and not use a loop, you could also do something like:

```
par(mfcol = c(ncol(data), 1))
Map(function(x,y) plot(x, main =y), data, names(data))
```

Comment: Thank you, even if it's related to time series I think it can help me to grasp my data. I like one-liner!

Comment: Just a small note: when adding 'plot.type=c("single")', your series is plotted on a single plot, instead of separate boxes:
 
    `data <- data.frame(x=c(rnorm(10)),y=c(rnorm(10)),z=c(rnorm(10)))
plot.ts(data,plot.type=c("single"),lty=1:3)`

Comment: @GeekOnAcid +1, Thank you very much for the hint to "single".

Comment: If you are going to use `single`, you should also add: `col=rainbow(ncol(my.data))` or something similar to keep the lines readable.

Answer (score 15):

You can jump through hoops and convert your solution to a `lapply`, `sapply` or `apply` call. (I see @jonw shows one way to do this.) Other than that what you have already is perfectly acceptable code.

If these are all a time series or similar then the following might be a suitable alternative, which plots each series in it's own panel on a single plotting region. We use the `zoo` package as it handles ordered data like this very well indeed.

```
require(zoo)
set.seed(1)
## example data
dat <- data.frame(X = cumsum(rnorm(100)), Y = cumsum(rnorm(100)),
                  Z = cumsum(rnorm(100)))
## convert to multivariate zoo object
datz <- zoo(dat)
## plot it
plot(datz)
```

Which gives:
[image: Example of zoo plotting capabilities]

Answer (score 14):

I'm surprised that no one mentioned `matplot`. It's pretty convenient in case you don't need to plot each line in separate axes.
Just one command:

```
matplot(y = data, type = 'l', lty = 1)
```

Use `?matplot` to see all the options.

To add the legend, you can set color palette and then add it:

```
mypalette = rainbow(ncol(data))
matplot(y = data, type = 'l', lty = 1, col = mypalette)
legend(legend = colnames(data), x = "topright", y = "topright", lty = 1, lwd = 2, col = mypalette)
```

Comment: What is `matlab.dark.palette`, where is it from?

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson it's a color palette function I usually use. It's from `hyperSpec` package. But it would be better to use more known function here, so I changed it to `rainbow`. If you're not aware of palette functions take a look at `?rainbow`. Sorry for confusing.

Answer (score 9):

Using some of the tips above (especially thanks @daroczig for the `names(df)[i]` form) this function prints a histogram for numeric variables and a bar chart for factor variables. A good start to exploring a data frame:

```
par(mfrow=c(3,3),mar=c(2,1,1,1)) #my example has 9 columns

dfplot <- function(data.frame)
{
  df <- data.frame
  ln <- length(names(data.frame))
  for(i in 1:ln){
    mname <- substitute(df[,i])
      if(is.factor(df[,i])){
        plot(df[,i],main=names(df)[i])}
        else{hist(df[,i],main=names(df)[i])}
  }
}
```

Best wishes, Mat.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, ggplot2 does not offer a way to do this (easily) without transforming your data into long format. You can try to fight it but it will just be easier to do the data transformation. Here all the methods, including `melt` from reshape2, `gather` from tidyr, and `pivot_longer` from tidyr: [Reshaping data.frame from wide to long format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185252/reshaping-data-frame-from-wide-to-long-format)

Here's a simple example using [`pivot_longer`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html):

```
> df <- data.frame(time = 1:5, a = 1:5, b = 3:7)
> df
  time a b
1    1 1 3
2    2 2 4
3    3 3 5
4    4 4 6
5    5 5 7

> df_long <- df %>% pivot_longer(c(a, b), names_to = "colname", values_to = "val")
> df_long
# A tibble: 10 x 3
    time colname   val
   <int> <chr>   <int>
 1     1 a           1
 2     1 b           3
 3     2 a           2
 4     2 b           4
 5     3 a           3
 6     3 b           5
 7     4 a           4
 8     4 b           6
 9     5 a           5
10     5 b           7
```

As you can see, `pivot_longer` puts the selected column names in whatever is specified by `names_to` (default "name"), and puts the long values into whatever is specified by `values_to` (default "value").   If I'm ok with the default names, I can use use `df %>% pivot_longer(c("a", "b"))`.

Now you can plot as normal:

```
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = time, y = val, color = colname)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: I would add `require(tidyr)` and `require(ggplot2)` to your answer so it will become a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: @AlessandroJacopson I thought I made it obvious those were required. Anyway is the MWE useful if the code is interspersed with explanation?

Comment: To me it is useful, anyway it's a matter of taste, thank you for your answer.

Comment: I agree with @AlessandroJacopson since most people only look at the code

Comment: @Julien maybe it's better people read the answer before copy pasting code!

Answer (score 5):

With `lattice`:

```
library(lattice)

df <- data.frame(time = 1:10,
                 a = cumsum(rnorm(10)),
                 b = cumsum(rnorm(10)),
                 c = cumsum(rnorm(10)))

form <- as.formula(paste(paste(names(df)[- 1],  collapse = ' + '),  
                         'time',  sep = '~'))

xyplot(form,  data = df,  type = 'b',  outer = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could specify the title (and also the title of the axes via `xlab` and `ylab`) with the `main` option. E.g.:

```
plot(data[,i], main=names(data)[i])
```

And if you want to plot (and save) each variable of a dataframe, you should use `png`, `pdf` or any other graphics driver you need, and after that issue a `dev.off()` command. E.g.:

```
data <- read.csv("sample.csv",header=T,sep=",")
for (i in 1:length(data)) {
    pdf(paste('fileprefix_', names(data)[i], '.pdf', sep='')
    plot(data[,i], ylab=names(data[i]), type="l")
    dev.off()
}
```

Or draw all plots to the same image with the `mfrow` paramater of `par()`. E.g.: use `par(mfrow=c(2,2)` to include the next 4 plots in the same "image".

Answer (score 3):

I don't have R on this computer, but here is a crack at it. You can use `par` to display multiple plots in a window, or like this to prompt for a click before displaying the next page.

```
plotfun <- function(col) 
  plot(data[ , col], ylab = names(data[col]), type = "l")
par(ask = TRUE)
sapply(seq(1, length(data), 1), plotfun)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case the column names in the `.csv` file file are not valid R name:

```
data <- read.csv("sample.csv",sep=";",head=TRUE)
data2 <- read.csv("sample.csv",sep=";",head=FALSE,nrows=1)

for ( i in seq(1,length( data ),1) ) plot(data[,i],ylab=data2[1,i],type="l")
```

Comment: Since you use only first row from data2, it would be more efficient to set `nrows = 1` in `read.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

This link helped me a lot for the same problem:

```
p = ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data = df_plot, aes(x = idx, y = col1), color = "blue") +
  geom_line(data = df_plot, aes(x = idx, y = col2), color = "red") 

print(p)
```

https://rpubs.com/euclid/343644