# ggplot with Strings on x-Axis

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, dataframe

I'm trying to draw a plot with several curves in it. The x-axis are not numerical values, but Strings.

This works fine (like in [how to plot all the columns of a data frame in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877357/how-to-plot-all-the-columns-of-a-data-frame-in-r)):

```
require(ggplot2)
df_ok <- rbind(data.frame(x=4:1,y=rnorm(4),d="d1"),data.frame(x=3:1,y=rnorm(3),d="d2"))
ggplot(df_ok, aes(x,y)) + geom_line(aes(colour=d))
```

But my data looks like this:

```
require(ggplot2)
df_nok <- rbind(data.frame(x=c("four","three","two","one"),y=rnorm(4),d="d1"),data.frame(x=c("three","two","one"),y=rnorm(3),d="d2"))
ggplot(df_nok, aes(x,y)) + geom_line(aes(colour=d))
```

I get the error **geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?**.
Even though the graph lines do not appear, the axis are plotted, and the x-Axis contains the correct Labels - but also in *wrong order*.

Any idea how to plot this as easy as possible? (Also note the missing x-values for some series).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Your problem is that the `x` variable is a factor. So, change your data frame and make `x` a double:

```
df = rbind(data.frame(x=4:1,y=rnorm(4),d="d1"), 
           data.frame(x=3:1,y=rnorm(3),d="d2"))
```

Plot as normal

```
g = ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_line(aes(colour=d))
```

but alter the x-axis scaling explicitly:

```
g + scale_x_continuous(breaks=1:4, labels=c("one", "two", "three", "four"))
```

---

To rename your variable, try something like:

```
x1 = factor(df_nok$x, 
            levels=c("one", "two", "three", "four"), 
            labels=1:4)
df$x1 = as.numeric(x1)
```

Comment: I'd love to not have to reshape my data. But if no one else has an idea, I will accept this answer.

Comment: Have you an idea how I easily could reshape my data to this form when I have got `df_nok` and a wanted order of `x`?

Comment: i would upvote you ten if i could. must remember `as.is=TRUE` pretty much all the time! Had a second problem problem was caused by date being character after setting `as.is=TRUE` but that was easily solved with an `as.Date()`.

Comment: Aren't you just love R and Stack Overflow? Fantastic!

Answer (score 7):

You can convince ggplot to draw lines by adding a dummy group,

```
ggplot(df_nok, aes(x,y)) + geom_line(aes(colour=d, group=d))
```

Also see http://kohske.wordpress.com/2010/12/27/faq-geom_line-doesnt-draw-lines/

Comment: This does not work correctly. It draws one line with coloured segments, but not 2 seperate lines.

Comment: It should be `group=d`, not `group=1`.

Comment: Great stuff! Now only the order is wrong anymore ("four","one","three","two"). Any quick help for that?

Comment: sorry i read this too quickly, glad you got a better answer. PS: the order can be changed by making `x` a factor with levels in the order you want them displayed.

Comment: @baptiste: but it works fine with the trick Brian Diggs commented above (except for sort order)! Edit your answer above and earn an upvote!

Answer (score 4):

Add in the `group` aesthetic (sort of redundant, I know, but much simpler than re-jigging the axis labels).

```
df_nok <- rbind(data.frame(x=c("four","three","two","one"),y=rnorm(4),d="d1"),data.frame(x=c("three","two","one"),y=rnorm(3),d="d2"))

ggplot(df_nok, aes(x,y, group=d)) + geom_line(aes(colour=d))
```

It's true your x-axis is still probably not in the order you want. As noted by @csgillespie you can fix this by making it into a factor

```
df_nok$x <- factor(df_nok$x, 
            levels=c("one", "two", "three", "four"), 
            labels=1:4)
```

Comment: Better a year late than never, right? Well anyway, this will be for people like me who stumble into this in the future.