# Ggplot: Same data not plotting aline plot, but making a bar plot (Each group consist of only one observation.)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a line plot from the following data:

```
> dput(agdata)
structure(list(date = c("2014-11-30", "2014-12-01", "2014-12-02", 
"2014-12-03", "2014-12-04", "2014-12-05", "2014-12-06", "2014-12-07", 
"2014-12-14", "2014-12-15", "2014-12-16", "2014-12-17", "2014-12-18"
), A = c(86.3333333333333, 91.1666666666667, 83.4, 83, 86, 94.75, 
78, 87, 87, 92, 98.6, 87, 85.3333333333333), B = c(1015.16666666667, 
1014.33333333333, 1017.2, 1021, 1017.5, 1021.5, 1029, 1022, 1009, 
1012.4, 1014.8, 1011, 1011), C = c(8.55666666666667, 7.145, 7.51, 
4.61, 4.335, 3.2625, 6.585, 8.35, 9.09, 6.48, 2.532, 11.74, 11.7933333333333
), D = c(24, 74.6666666666667, 77, 57.5, 82.5, 56.25, 0, 88, 
32, 61, 50, 92, 80.6666666666667)), .Names = c("date", "A", "B", 
"C", "D"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

I tried this:

```
ggplot(data = agdata,aes(x = date, y = A)) + geom_line(stat="identity")
```

and various other parameters, including removing the stat parameter, moving aes to geom_line, and a few others.
I keep getting:

```
geom_path: Each group consist of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group aesthetic?
```

To check if the data is fine, I tried:

```
ggplot(data = agdata,aes(x = date, y = A)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

which works just fine.

Any pointers as to what I'm missing here? I have a feeling it has something to do with a `group=` parameter in `aes()` by looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16776450/ggplot2-each-group-consists-of-only-one-observation), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21337110/ggplot-each-group-consists-of-only-one-observation), but not sure what.

Comment: Thanks for the downvote :P Don't want to delete, as it can serve as a reference to other rockheaded folks like me.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh, nevermind. Figured it the minute I posted this. it gas to be `group=1` in `aes()`.

Feel rockheaded now.