# Plot multiple Y variables in a scatter plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, scatter-plot

I tried the following code

```
plot(start, Pinkpop_df1[3:5,])
```

But I get an error;

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) :     'x' and 'y'
>   lengths differ

How can I plot multiple Y variables for each x variable? (start is the x variable for which I want to plot multiple y variables in the same scatterplot)

Comment: You should probably tidy your data and map colours from the resulting `var` column. But hard to say because your code is not reproducible.

Comment: Data is tidy, I just used the wrong approach. Found this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877357/how-to-plot-all-the-columns-of-a-data-frame-in-r and it solved my problem. Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
plot(cbind(start,Pinkpop_df1[3:5,]))
```

There are several ways of calling plot and your tried a wrong mix of them.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Found this topic which helped me out; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877357/how-to-plot-all-the-columns-of-a-data-frame-in-r