# scatterplot for a dataframe with 1000 columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

How can I draw scatter plot of a data.frame that has 1000 columns? I see ggpairs is good but sounds useful when I have limited number of columns.
I don't think a for loop for ggplot is the most efficient way. What other methods do you suggest?

Comment: what will you eventually so with 1M plots?

Comment: When I plot, I first ask myself "what do I want my data to show"? Ideally, everything, but if volume becomes prohibitive, I start breaking it down and summarizing. To drill to the bedrock of my writing, what are you trying to show?

Comment: you can try `plot(mtcars)` although even with just 11 columns this gets messy. or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877357/how-to-plot-all-the-columns-of-a-data-frame-in-r