# Trying to make a list of ggplot objects in a for loop; all items in list are written as last iteration from loop

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to build a list of ggplot objects.  I want to plot one variable on the x axis but plot each of the other variables in the data frame in the y.  When I run the loop all of my values end up being the same as the last variable.

I'm hoping to use the grid.arrange function to plot all the graphs on one page.

My reprex:

```
library(ggplot2)

 l <- list()
for(i in 2:11){
    p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = mtcars[,i])) + geom_smooth() + geom_point()
    name <- paste("p",i,sep="_")
    tmp <- list(p)
    l[[name]] <- tmp
}
print(l$p_2)
print(l$p_3)
```

Comment: Using a loop probably isn't the best way to solve the issue. It's better to describe your original problem rather than your assumed solution to the problem. Would something like this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877357/how-to-plot-all-the-columns-of-a-data-frame-in-r

Comment: I did describe my original problem in the first 2 sentences. The link you sent is not the same.  I cannot plot on the same graph because my variables have unique scales like they do in the reprex.  I looked at facet_grid but it uses a static value for aes(y =).

Comment: Here's my tidyverse solution which I think is a lot cleaner than the ones below, now the question is closed https://gist.github.com/jackbrookes/3bbcc47cdd246b3d8a9173a4b9bacf43

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a list of plots directly using `sapply`. For example:

```
plist = sapply(names(mtcars)[-grep("mpg", names(mtcars))], function(col) {
  ggplot(mtcars, aes_string(x = "mpg", y = col)) + geom_smooth() + geom_point()
}, simplify=FALSE)
```

The list elements (each of which is a ggplot object) will be named after the y variable in the plot:

```
names(plist)
```

> ```
> [1] "cyl"  "disp" "hp"   "drat" "wt"   "qsec" "vs"   "am"   "gear" "carb"
> ```

You can print all the plots by typing `plist` in the console. Or, for a single plot, just select the plot you want:

```
plist[["hp"]]
```

[image]

For a situation like this, you might prefer faceting, which requires converting the data from wide to long format. You can have facets with different y scales by setting `scales="free_y"`.

```
library(tidyverse)

ggplot(gather(mtcars, key, value, -mpg), aes(mpg, value)) + 
  geom_smooth() + geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~ key, scales="free_y", ncol=5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Subset the data frame before calling `ggplot`, and then use `aes_string` to call column names as string.

```
library(ggplot2)

l <- list()
for(i in 2:11){
  temp <- mtcars[, c(1, i)]
  p <- ggplot(temp, aes_string(x = "mpg", y = names(temp)[2])) + geom_smooth() + geom_point()
  name <- paste("p",i,sep="_")
  tmp <- list(p)
  l[[name]] <- tmp
}
print(l$p_2)
```

[image]

```
print(l$p_3)
```

[image]