# Issues plotting multiple columns into a single plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I used [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877357/how-to-plot-all-the-columns-of-a-data-frame-in-r) to find some code to plot multiple columns into one plot, but when I tried using the code I get a plot with everything but the data points and this error message

> "geom_path: Each group consists of only one observation. Do you need to adjust the group
>   aesthetic?"

original data

[image]

converted data

[image]

the code I used:

```
df <- melt(Cooks_Farm_Cations_2017, id.vars = 'Site', variable.name = "Cation")

pa1<-ggplot(df, mapping=aes(Site,value)) + geom_line(aes(color=Cation))+ylab("mg/L")
```

My goal is to get a line plot of my 4 cations(y) for each sample site (x).
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try adding `group = Cation` like so: `geom_line(aes(color=Cation, group = Cation))`. If that doesn't work, use `geom_line(aes(color=Cation), group = 1)`

Comment: Fixed! Thank you!

Comment: I put the information in an answer--go ahead and accept it so others with the same question can make use of yours--thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw parallel coordinates, you can make use of `geom_line`'s `group` aesthetic

```
ggplot(df, mapping=aes(Site,value)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=Cation, group = Cation)) + 
  ylab("mg/L")
```